# .NET 4.7.2 Class Library with simplified csproj format can't be referenced by ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, msbuild

I am trying to update `csproj` files, for class libraries targeting .NET 4.7.2, to the newer, simplified format detailed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/tools/csproj.md).

I have an ASP.NET Core project which targets `netcoreapp2.0` and references the class libraries mentioned previously. This builds fine as long as the .NET Framework projects have the old `csproj` file format.

Is it a known shortcoming that .NET Framework projects can't use the newer `csproj` format and be referenced in a project targeting `netcoreapp`?

Comment: What is the actual error message you are getting?

Comment: @Neil `Project Net472Project is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp, Version=v2.0), Project Net472Project supports: net472 (.NETFramework, Version=v4.7.2)`

Answer (score 1):

The compatibility level of asset / fallback targets for .NET Core and .NET Standard 2.* currently is 4.6.1.
So in theory, you could get it to work by targeting 4.6.1 instead of 4.7.2 and using latest tooling. This fallback was orignally only planned for NuGet packages when you consumed libraries that you can't control yourself.

You should re-target your class library to netstandard2.0 or netcoreapp2.0 though to ensure you're only using available APIs. This project can then be used from other .NET Framework projects.

If you are unable to do that for some reason, you can also modify the project reference:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\som\netfx47-project.csproj"
    SkipGetTargetFrameworkProperties="true" />
```

Comment: This did not work. As you mentioned, I think the only solution is to convert to `netstandard` or `netcoreapp`.